# Wrong evaluating expression in variable C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 C# with Unity.  The value of `cell.x` is wrong after evaluation.

```
PointCell cell = new PointCell();
cell.x = (int)((point.x - (discretization / 2f)) / discretization);
cell.y = (int)((point.y - (discretization / 2f)) / discretization);
return cell;

point.x = 4.32f and discretization = 0,32f
```

It should evaluate to 13, but it is evaluating to 12.

See print debug watches.

[image: code]
watches:
[image: watches]

Can anyone explain this?

Edit:
PointCell code:

```
public class PointCell
{
    public PointCell()
    {
        x = y = 0;
    }
    public PointCell(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int x, y;
}
```

Comment: Where is the class `PointCell` coming from?

Comment: Most likely floating point inaccuracy.  the result could be `12.99999` which would be truncated to `12` when converted to an int.  Maybe you should use `Math.Round` instead of casting to `int`?

Comment: @DStanley `(int)((point.x - (discretization / 2f)) / discretization);` evaluates to 13, so I assume either the getter or setter of `cell.x` is getting/setting it to 12 for some reason.

Comment: @Quantic That's possible, although we'd need to see the setter to be certain.

Comment: @DStanley And, it's not possible that it's floating point inaccuracy, as his `watches` screenshot shows, right?

Comment: Is `PointCell` a struct?

Comment: it's 13 for me. Have a look: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BFlrXL

Comment: I'm getting something different than his watches. If I break out all the variables and do it line by line: `float floatNum = (4.32f - (0.32f / 2)) / 0.32f;` then `floatNum` will contain `13.000001`. When I execute `int intNum = (int)floatNum;` then `intNum` contains `13`. Is this some weird quirk with Unity?

Comment: @DStanley Convert.ToInt32 works. It must be that you said. I can't use Round in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't this be dependent on the processor?  Isn't a floating point 2 really not a 2, and isn't it's precision dependent on the processor bits (32 or 64 bit)?  Seems like if his processor is different from the ones other people are using here, that would explain the different results.  A relevant article is here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx.  Bottom line, you can't depend on floating points not being off by a tiny portion, and if you round off a float that is very close to a whole number, you might get this sort of problem.

Comment: Bill Rock - can you create a simple non-unity fiddle on your machine, like maybe just a plain c# console app, and do this same arithmetic and see what result you get?  My guess is that this has to do with representation of floats, and not with Unity quirks.